# SAS Independence Test Loop

Tags: sas

I am a new user of SAS. Hope you could help me with this.
For example, I have a data set with 35 categorical variables.
`cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 ... cat35`
I want to create a table consisting the result of independence test between all possible combination of two categorical variables and its p-values.
I used `proc freq` but I can only do it manually, two variables at a time. To save time, I'm thinking to use macro, but I don't know how to do it.

The output is a table
`Variable1 | Variable2 | P-value`
`----------------------------------------------`
`cat1      | cat2      | p-value of cat1 & cat2`
`cat1      | cat3      | p-value of cat1 & cat3`
`...`
`cat34     | cat35     | p-value of cat34 & cat35`

Open for suggestions. Thanks!

**Edit:** My current code is
`proc freq data = mydata; tables cat1*cat2 / chisq; output out=myoutput pchi cramv; run;`
`proc sql; create table myoutput as select "cat1" as X, "cat2" as Y, P_PCHI from myoutput; quit;`
This will give a table
`X    | Y    | P-value`
`-----------------------------------`
`cat1 | cat2 | p-value of cat1 & cat2`

Comment: Can you include the code you'd use to do this with one variable pair, please, and some sample data with a few variables?

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need some more detail here

Comment: I've updated my answer - I think it now does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this using the following syntax for the tables statement within your proc freq call:

```
tables (cat1-cat35) * (cat1-cat35);
```

I've adapted your code to capture the desired output in a SAS dataset:

```
data example;
  do cat1 = 'a','b','c';
    do cat2 = 'd','e','f';
      do cat3 = 'g','h','i';
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;

ods output chisq = mychisq(where = (statistic = 'Chi-Square'));

proc freq data = example; 
tables (cat1-cat3) * (cat1-cat3) / chisq; 
output out=myoutput pchi cramv; 
run;
```

This gives you the output in a slightly different format, but you should be able to sort it out from there.

Comment: Are you sure this works? This syntax doesn't work for me at all

Comment: @JonathanWilson Example added.

Answer (score 0):

one way to loop through all pairs is to do

```
do i=1 to 34;
     do j=i+1 to 35;
       .....
```